# How to implement this rule in ANTLR4?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

How to implement this rule in ANTLR4:

> multiline-comment-text-item -> Any Unicode scalar value except /* or */

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ANTLR, you cannot say: "match this-or-that character, except these multiple (!) characters". You can only say "match this-or-that character, except these single (!) characters":

```
ANY_EXCEPT_STAR : ~[*];
ANY_EXCEPT_FSLASH : ~[/];
```

But doing `FOO : ~[/*];` matches any single character except a `/` and `*`.

I wouldn't match `multiline-comment-text-item` in a lexer rule of its own, but rather inside the `multiline-comment-text` where it's (most likely) used:

```
MultilineCommentText
 : '/*' .*? '*/'
 ;
```

Be sure to include the `?` in there, making it ungreedy.

Note that quite often, such tokens are hidden or discarded so that they won't end up in parser rules. In that case do either:

```
MultilineCommentText
 : '/*' .*? '*/' -> skip
 ;
```

or

```
MultilineCommentText
 : '/*' .*? '*/' -> channel(HIDDEN)
 ;
```

See: https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/lexer-rules.md

Answer (score 0):

I've just met this rule when trying to parse Swift with ANTLR4. Following is my implementation:

```
MULTILINE_COMMENT
    : '/*' ('/'*? MULTILINE_COMMENT | ('/'* | '*'*) ~[/*])*? '*'*? '*/'
;
```

It's unnecessary to split `multiline-comment` into that many subrules as in the document.